# Face glitch with black plasma rig

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, rigging, bones

I am building a Minecraft animation in blender with the black plasma rig, which is made by Pixel Frosty. The problem is that the face is behind the mesh/skin. If I look at all the other rigs on YouTube the face is at the front. I've looked all over YouTube and I'm new to blender so I don't know most of the controls. How do I fix this? Here's a picture of the outside [image] and here's a picture of the inside [image]

Comment: try Pose -> Clear Transform -> All (lower right menus), and see what happens.

Comment: Sorry, as I said I am new to blender where are the menus?

Comment: I did what you said Sazerac and it didn't change anything.

Comment: this link has the solution to your problem https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=GCaR3i11580

Answer (score 1):

I just found out that it's the second layer covering the face. Since you don't have a second layer in you skin, blender doesn't know what is tranparent. Blender will use the texture of the primary layer and put it on the second. If you had a second layer, blender will know what should be transparent and fix it.

You can either use a skin with a second layer so blender makes part of the second layer transparent or hide the whole second layer in the outliner.

To hide it, enable "disable in render" under filter in the outliner.
[image: Show "disable in render" button with the camera icon]

Then, search for the second layer under your rig and disable it.
[image: Disable the second layer in render]

You can also disable it in the viewport with the eye icon.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed by using a skin with a 3D hat layer, it didn't work in the first place because the wasn't holes in the face for the eyes. Thanks for the help anyway!

Answer (score -1):

You can also try to select the eyes and the mouth and move it out! But for that you need to go to edit mode!